# How do I schedule this .ps1 file to run daily?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I have a .ps1 file that works when I run it in PowerShell (it registers a filesystemwatcher to watch for changes in an excel file), but I can't get it to work when I schedule it in task scheduler.

Is this because my inputs are off or do I need to export this .ps1 into something else?

**My inputs-**

Program = PowerShell.exe

Add arguments = -ExecutionPolicy Bypass \blah blah blah\testing file.ps1

Start in is empty

Comment: It should work, start logging some check points in PS script to see further

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Action: Start a program

Program: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "\blah blah blah\testing file.ps1"